# Best way to convert single element IEnumerable to just the single element?

Tags: .net, ienumerable

If I have an IEnumerable object in my .net code that contains a single element, what is the best way to convert the IEnumerable to a single object while checking that the IEnumerable does, indeed, contain only one element?

Here are a couple of ideas that come to mind:

```
IEnumerable<string> strings = getStrings();
if (string.Count() != 0 ) throw new Exception();
else return strings.First();

return getStrings().Single(x => true);
```

Comment: Sure, I'll look. Sometimes when I have a question which has no correct answers I will either show how I resolved the issue in an answer or flag the question as needing to be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to raise an exception anyways, you can just use:

```
return getStrings().Single();
```

This will automatically raise an `InvalidOperationException` if there is more than one string in the enumeration.

Comment: Thanks! Somehow, it got by me that you can call `.Single()` with no argument.